# SQL : Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried query like this but i got message like

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Code:

```
select
    MaterialID = REPLACE(MaterialID, 'MA','Material'),
    MaterialName = UPPER(MaterialName),
    (select
         PurchaseDate,
         PurchaseQty
     from
         MsPurchase
     where 
         PurchaseQty > AVG(PurchaseQty))
from
    MsMaterial
where
    MaterialType = 'supplies'
```

Comment: And what part of the message is not clear?

Comment: This query does not really make sense. Please explain what you are trying to do, and provide sample data and expected results as tabular text.

Comment: (1) Explain the logic you want to implement.  A non-working query does not convey this information.  (2) Provide sample data.  (3) Provide desired results.  (4) Add a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: i try to show MaterialID, MaterialName, PurchaseDate, Quantity where the MateriakType  is supplies and the Quantity greater than average.

but that data from 2 table table Material and Purchase but i must use subquerry

this is link sample data https://imgur.com/a/SFX4FJB
thx

Comment: sorry i annoy you but i got the answer from other thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need below -

```
select
    m1.MaterialID = REPLACE(MaterialID, 'MA','Material'),
    m1.MaterialName = UPPER(MaterialName),
    m2.PurchaseDate,
    m2.PurchaseQty
from
    MsMaterial m1
join (select
        PurchaseDate,
        PurchaseQty,
        MaterialID
     from
         MsPurchase
     where 
        PurchaseQty > AVG(PurchaseQty)
    ) m2 on m1.MaterialID = m2.MaterialID
where
    MaterialType = 'supplies'
```